# Xamarin.Forms Bindable Properties

Tags: xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

It may sound like a dumb question but why are bindable properties static?

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty MapSpanProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "MapSpan",
    returnType: typeof(MapSpan),
    declaringType: typeof(BindableMap),
    defaultValue: null,
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
    propertyChanged: MapSpanPropertyChanged);

public MapSpan MapSpan
{
    get
    {
        return (MapSpan)GetValue(MapSpanProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MapSpanProperty, value);
    }
}
```

I have this code and it works just fine if I make the bindable property static, otherwise, it doesn't work. If I make this bindable property static it means, let's say if I have 2 maps opened at the same time, that this value will be the same on both if I set it on one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Each bindable property has a corresponding `public static readonly` field of type `BindableProperty` that is exposed on the same class and that is the identifier of the bindable property.

You could check the source code of the control which provide the binable property.

I use the contentview for example. The code is from the link below. [Xamarin forms update viewmodel field from a bindable property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238405/xamarin-forms-update-viewmodel-field-from-a-bindable-property)

```
public partial class MyCustomControl : ContentView
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
             nameof(Text),
             typeof(string),
             typeof(MyCustomControl),
             string.Empty,
             propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
             {
                 var control = bindable as MyCustomControl;
                 //var changingFrom = oldValue as string;
                 //var changingTo = newValue as string;
                 control.Title.Text = newValue.ToString();
             });
    
    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The `ContentView` provide the public static readonly BindableProperty.

```
  //
// Summary:
//     An element that contains a single child element.
//
// Remarks:
//     The following example shows how to construct a new ContentView with a Label inside.
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class ContentView : TemplatedView
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Backing store for the Xamarin.Forms.ContentView.Content property..
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     To be added.
    public static readonly BindableProperty ContentProperty;

    public ContentView();

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the content of the ContentView.
    public View Content { get; set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Method that is called when the binding context changes.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     To be added.
    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged();
}
```

You could check the MS docs about more for the static in binable property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, it's static just for get describing data before moment of creation.
But it's not being used as static. BindableObject base class define INSTANСE of `Dictionary<BindablePropery, BindablePropertyContext>`. BindablePropertyContext contains our value. It means that each our class has static BindablePropery, but every of them get it's own context from it's own dictionary.